# Weird behaviour of C for loop with i++ as condition

Tags: c, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
int main()
{
    char i = 0;

    for (; i++; printf("%d", i));

    printf("%d", i);

    return 0;
}
```

It successfully compiles and prints `1`. I am new to C and I don't understand this. I thought i++ will always be true and so it will be an infinite loop.

Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: I think i++ is false that's why loop break at initial point. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: The value of the `i++` expression is `i`. It is as if the value is temporarily stored so that it can be the old value.

Comment: Your indentation is also misleading; your for loop has an empty body.

Comment: @Mat sorry about that, fixed it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i++` is *post-increment*. So at the time of checking the statement, the value of `i` is `0`, which is `false`. Hence, the loop breaks.

Comment: In case of ++i, the loop will be infinite, right? If i=1, what is the behavior of the loop?

Comment: @kvk30 Not really. The value of `i` will progress from `1 ... 127, -128 ... -1, 0` at which point the condition will fail again.

Comment: @CinCout -- if bare `char` is `unsigned` then it will wrap around after `i` reaches `CHAR_MAX`, but if `char` is `signed` the arithmetic will overflow and behavior is undefined.

Comment: @DavidBowling Why is the behavior different for `signed` and `unsigned`? Shouldn't wrap around happen in either case?

Comment: The Standard provides that [`unsigned` arithmetic can never overflow](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p9), and instead has wraparound. But this is not so for `signed` arithmetic, which can overflow, leading to [UB since the value can't be represented in the underlying type](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p5). Or, [see this](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3p3).

Comment: @kvk30 So the wrap-around behavior is valid only if the `char` is `unsigned`. So the values of `i` will range from `1...255, 0` at which point the condition will fail. If the `char` is `signed` underlying, it is `undefined behavior` and seeing the wrap-around is just one of many possible deceptive outcomes of UB.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>     for (; i++; printf("%d", i));
> ```

is *legal* C code, but is not *idiomatic* C code. Real C programmers never code like this (but can understand what happens). Read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (it practically is the C standard) §6.8.5.3 for the meaning of `for`:

> 6.8.5.3 The for statement
>
> 1 The statement
>
> ```
>       for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
> ```
>
> behaves as follows: The expression expression-2 is the controlling
>   expression that is evaluated before each execution of the loop body.
>   The expression expression-3 is evaluated as a void expression after
>   each execution of the loop body. If clause-1 is a declaration, the
>   scope of any identifiers it declares is the remainder of the
>   declaration and the entire loop, including the other two expressions;
>   it is reached in the order of execution before the first evaluation of
>   the controlling expression. If clause-1 is an expression, it is
>   evaluated as a void expression before the first evaluation of the
>   controlling expression.158)
>
> 2 Both clause-1 and expression-3 can be omitted. An omitted
>   expression-2 is replaced by a nonzero constant.
>
> Footnotes
>
> 158) Thus, clause-1 specifies initialization for the loop, possibly
>   declaring one or more variables for use in the loop; the controlling
>   expression, expression-2, specifies an evaluation made before each
>   iteration, such that execution of the loop continues until the
>   expression compares equal to 0; and expression-3 specifies an
>   operation (such as incrementing) that is performed after each
>   iteration.

So, in your case, the controlling expression (the "`expression-2`" in the C standard) is (wrongly) `i++`. It happens to be false on the first time the loop is taken.

If you replace `i++` by `++i` the condition stays true for 255 times on my Linux computer (since I have unsigned chars on 8 bits).

If your computer has signed chars, you technically have some [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because you have a signed overflow. So be *very* [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) and read [Lattner's blog](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) on UB!

> I am new to C and I don't understand this.

Then you should read some [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) site, sometimes refer to the C11 standard [n1570](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html), read good books on C programming (perhaps even read good introduction to programming, such as [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) - which does *not* use C), and learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you use some [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, be sure to enable all warnings and debug info, so compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`.

Comment: Why is it undefined behaviour for signed chars? why is it different from unsigned chars?

Comment: IIRC signed overflow is an instance of undefined behavior.

Comment: okay, but why is its behaviour different from unsigned chars? why is it not wrapping around CHAR_MAX, like unsigned chars

Comment: Because the specification says that the behavior is in principle different. In practice, on your x86 computer running Linux, it is likely to be very similar for `signed` and `unsigned` char. In principle, it is not.

Comment: Yeah, in my computer the behaviour is indeed same! Thanks for clearing this up!

Comment: You absolutely need to read more about undefined behavior, notably [Lattner's blog](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) on it